# Estimate negative binomial dispersion parameter $k$ using mean and proportion of zeros

Tags: distributions, inference, probabilistic-programming

I came across supplemental methods of [a paper](https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1038%2Fnature04153/MediaObjects/41586_2005_BFnature04153_MOESM1_ESM.pdf) estimating the mean ($R$) and dispersion ($k$) of a negative binomial distribution that stated:

> Page 8: "Given estimates of the mean ($\hat{R}$) and proportion of zeros ($\hat{p_0}$) of a negative binomial distribution, the parameter $k$ can be estimated by solving the equation $\hat{p_0} = (1+\frac{\hat{R}}{k})^{-k}$ numerically."

This "zero-class estimator" approach is also used [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2529470?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents).

I would like to compare the accuracy of this method (with regards to inference of $k$) with my results using MLE. This initially seemed simple, but I have been unable to successfully estimate $k$ using this approach in R programming. I tried solving for $k$ algebraically but my algebra may be wrong (happy to post if requested, but omitting equations for readability/brevity).

Any advice on how to use this approach to estimate $k$ (in R or other statistical software) would be much appreciated.

Comment: There [may be a solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+p%3D%281%2BR%2Fk%29%5E%28-k%29+for+k) for  $\hat k$ using the Lambert W function though you will need $p_0>0$

Comment: Thank you! This agrees with my algebraic approach but I seem to be unable to implement this in the actual statistical software. I am pasting below a computational solution I have found works

Comment: That paper to which you linked needed to be typed up in $\LaTeX.$ Looks like Word was used - very ugly.

Comment: @Henry: Unfortunately, the solution utilizing the Lambert $W$ function is incredibly numerically unstable. The denominator of the result is absolutely tiny, which is suspicious to me. I don't think the algebraic solution is feasible. That's why I deleted my answer.

Comment: @AdrianKeister perhaps you should be using the other branch of the Lambert W function.  Based on your deleted answer this would be `R=1.63;` `p=0.6667;` `-R*log(p)/(log(p)-R*lambertWm1(p^(1/R)*log(p)/R))` to get `0.1729429` as in jpsmith's table

Comment: Cross-posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4399484/solve-for-k-in-the-equation-hatp-0-1-frac-hatrk-k

Comment: @Henry: That's cool! But how to know which branch of the $W$ function is the correct one? Not sure it's obvious.

Comment: @AdrianKeister  It is probably related to $\ln(\hat{p}_0)$ being negative, and to get a positive estimate for $k$ you want  $W\!\left(\frac{\hat{p}_0^{1/{\hat{R}}}\,\ln(\hat{p}_0)}{\hat{R}}\right) < \frac{\ln(\hat{p}_0)}{\hat{R}}$.  The upper branch of the Lambert W function does not seem to achieve that for the cases I checked (though it was often close) while the lower branch does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $(1+\frac{\hat{R}}{k})^{-k}$ is a decreasing function of $k$, the function $\hat{p}_0 -(1+\frac{\hat{R}}{k})^{-k}$ will have at most one zero.  However, when the lower asymptote of $(1+\frac{\hat{R}}{k})^{-k}$ is larger than $\hat{p}_0$, no zero will be found.  Here's some simple R code

````
set.seed(555)
x = rnbinom(100,size=.5,prob=.4)
p0 = mean(x==0)
mu = mean(x)
f = function(k,p0,mu){
    return(p0 - (1+mu/k)^(-k))
}
uniroot(f,c(.001,1000),p0=p0,mu=mu)

```
````

Comment: Perfect - perhaps my initial attempt with `uniroot` didnt offer broad enough values as you mentioned below. Thank you!

Comment: @jpsmith Good to hear!  Always analyze properties of the normal equations, they can help you pick the correct optimization routine and show you how a sample can fail to produce a reasonable estimator.  A simple scatter plot or 3D plot is very useful for problems with no closed-form solutions for the estimators

Answer (score 3):

The exact answer can be given by the Lambert $W$ function as follows:
$$k=-\frac{\hat{R}\ln(\hat{p}_0)}{\ln(\hat{p}_0)-\hat{R}\,W\!\left(\frac{\hat{p}_0^{1/{\hat{R}}}\,\ln(\hat{p}_0)}{\hat{R}}\right)},$$
where $W$ is the Lambert $W$ function, which is the inverse of the function $f(x)=x\,e^{x}.$ In R, you can install the `lamW` package, which gives access to the `lambertWm1` function (a better branch of the $W$ function to use; see Henry's comment), and then code up the equation above as follows:

```
install.packages('lamW')
require(lamW)
k = - R * log(p) / (log(p) - R * lambertWm1(p^(1/R) * log(p) / R))
```

As mentioned in the comments, this does require $p>0$ to satisfy the domain requirements of the logarithm function.

Comment: Thank you! I initially tried this formula implemented through similar code but I am not getting results that align with established estimates. For instance, using data from the first column in the table [here](https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1038%2Fnature04153/MediaObjects/41586_2005_BFnature04153_MOESM4_ESM.pdf), $R = 1.63$ and $p_0 = 0.6667$, which should yield $k_{pz} = 0.17$ using the zero-class estimator. Using both my and your code with the `lamW` package function (as well as attempted with an alternate `LamberW` package) yields different results, $p_z = -1.190439e+16$.

Comment: I imagine we're getting some machine-epsilon problems: the denominator for your example is absolutely tiny. Lemme see if I can fix that somehow.

Comment: I'm not sure I can fix this. The denominator appears to be absolutely tiny for practically every input value you can dream up!

Comment: @jpsmith, That's because you used the $W_0$ branch and not the $W_{-1}$ branch. Using `R <- 1.63; p <- 0.6667` and `k <- - R * log(p) / (log(p) - R * lambertWm1(p^(1/R) * log(p) / R))` I get `0.1729429` for `k`. Disclosure, I am the author of the `lamW` package for `R`.

Comment: @Avraham Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this brute-force computational function that seems to work and avoids using the Lambert W function, though more accurate/elegant solutions may still be out there:

````
# Estimate k using only proportion of zeros (z=0, or y=1) and R

findk <- function(R, p0, k.maxsearch = 50, sigdig = 5){
  p0 <- round(p0, sigdig)
  k <- seq(10^-sigdig, k.maxsearch, 10^-sigdig)
  p <- round((1+(R/k))^-k, sigdig)
  see <- cbind(k, p, p0)
  if(tail(p, n = 1) > p0) {
    paste0("k > ", k.maxsearch)
    } else { 
  min(k[p == p0])
    }
}

# Test Function
    # Data rom Lloyd-Smith supplemental table 2, first page, found here: 
    # browseURL("https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1038%2Fnature04153/MediaObjects/41586_2005_BFnature04153_MOESM4_ESM.pdf")
ls_data <- data.frame(Rs = c(1.63, 0.94, 1.88, 0.63, 0.82, 1.32, 0.70), 
                      p0s = c(0.6667, 0.7273, 0.7059, 0.7394, 0.7143, 0.4054, 0.5500))

k_ests <- data.frame(ls_data,
                     k_pz = apply(ls_data, 1, function(x) findk(x[1], x[2])))

#   Rs    p0s    k_pz
# 1 1.63 0.6667 0.17294
# 2 0.94 0.7273 0.16946
# 3 1.88 0.7059 0.12576
# 4 0.63 0.7394 0.22758
# 5 0.82 0.7143 0.21317
# 6 1.32 0.4054 1.25930
# 7 0.70 0.5500 1.94307

# k_pz results match those found in paper table
```
````

Comment: Is the built-in ```uniroot``` function not working for you?  Should be quite easy to code, just give a big range of values for $k$ like (.001,1000)

Answer (score 1):

Given that both $\hat{p}_0$ and $(1+\frac{\hat{R}}{k})^{-k}$ are by definition non-negative, you can just minimize $(\hat{p}_0 - (1+\frac{\hat{R}}{k})^{-k})^2$. Almost any software will have some generic minimization tools (e.g. `ucminf` in `R`). The only difficulty will be the scenarios where the estimate of the dispersion parameter should be 0 or $\infty$ (depending on your parametrization), which is a genuine potential issue.